# Calling multiple WEB API calls with a Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap my head around Javascript Promises and am confused on where I need to put what.

The scenario is the following. I three JavaScript methods that each call out to a WEB API to save some data. For simplicity sake, I will call them SaveA(), SaveB() and SaveC(). I want them to fire SaveA() first and then have SaveB() fire after SaveA() has finished processing. Then the same scenario for SaveB() and SaveC().

The WEB API calls in the Save() methods return a null value when finished. I think this may be part of my confusion. These can be changed to return something else though if need be. The WEB API is written in C#. Below is a simplified version of what one of the WEB API methods look like.

```
//WEB API Signature
public ActionResult InsertSomething(SomeObjectModel model) { 
    Insert(model);
    return null;
}
```

Where am I supposed to put my SaveA call? Should it be in a Promise like below?

```
function SaveAPromise() {
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    try {
        SaveA();
    }
    catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
    fulfill("success");
});
```

}

If so, what do I do with the fulfill? Do I need to turn it into a function to call SaveB()?

Other examples I have seen online have shown stringing together calls using the then part. So does that mean I need to do something like this? If so, then what is the role of the fulfill method in SaveAPromise()?

```
var promise = SaveAPromise();
promise.then(SaveB());
promise.then(SaveC());
```

Thanks in advance for any help or clarification you can provide.

Comment: Are you trying to write a promise library, or use one.  If you are using one, then which one?  If you are writing one, I would consider using an existing one unless you are trying to write it for educational purposes.  In your immediate example

Comment: Also, in your example the full needs to go inside the try block. (Not my ultimate answer, just a comment on your example)

Comment: `.then()` takes an Anonymous or unexecuted function like `promise.then(SaveB).then(SaveC)`, unless of course your function returns the same. `resolve` argument function executes before `.then()`.

Comment: @SteveMitcham I am not trying to write a promise library. I just want to use the basic Promise functionality in JavaScript. Is there a library that needs to load? I am trying to test and am running into " JavaScript runtime error: 'Promise' is undefined"

Comment: The built in promises are part of the ECMAScript 6 specification and are not available in all browers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise  there are libraries that implement the functionality, one of the more popular ones is the Q library

Answer (score 0):

This is the [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) page on ECMA6 Promises.  Some excerpts from that page will explain what is going on for your situation.  Understand that compatibility for this technology is not guaranteed on all browsers.

```
function call(url) {
    // Return a new promise.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", url);


        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                resolve(http.response);
            } else {
                reject(http.response);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    });
}

call(saveAUrl).
  then(call(saveBUrl)).
  then(call(saveCUrl)).
  catch(function(error) {
    // handle error condition here
  }).
  then(function() {
    // handle final tasks with or without error
  })
```

So each call to the `call` method with the url to your 3 Save API calls is called in turn after each one is successful.  If any of them fail, the chain will shortcut to the catch clause.  The following then will be run whether or not the catch clause is triggered in case there is any final processing.  It is optional, however.

If you need to support ECMA 5, the [Q Promise Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) has similar functionality and syntax (not the same however), but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Chaining - Multiple Async Tasks in Sequence](http://bit.ly/1Er1tjL). It describes a promise pattern similar to your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

[As you can see here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining), you can chain `then()` calls. Try:

```
var promise = SaveAPromise();
promise
    .then(function(){
        SaveB();
    })
    .then(function(){
        SaveC()
    });
```

Comment: `.then()` should take an Anonymous or unexecuted function, unless your executed function returns the same.

Comment: You could just pass `SaveB` without `()` instead of wrapping it inside of an Anonymous function, unless you want to pass arguments to `SaveB`.